# How do I validate an input in elixir?

Tags: javascript, testing, elixir, ex-unit, hound

I am trying to write tests using hound and elixir and I cant seem to figure out a way to validate what was input into an input field... There is obviously a way to do this, but I have not figured out how to do so....

Example:

```
<input type="number" xpath="1" style="">
```

If I input 1 into this, how can I check that the field contains a 1?

I have been trying this method:

```
execute_script("document.querySelector(arguments[0]).value;", [
          "input[type='number']"
        ])
```

and this is giving me "nil"

Comment: Should that be `#target` instead of `#result`?

Comment: @sbacarob Sorry I corrected it, this is the scrip I try to execute on the proper element.

Comment: Have you tried using [Hound.Helpers.Element.attribute_value/2](https://hexdocs.pm/hound/Hound.Helpers.Element.html#attribute_value/2)?